# Opportunity team access

Tags: opportunity, opportunity-teams, access-modifier

I have given opportunity team member just read permission but he is also able to edit the fields. What might be the reason? The user is not in accounts team or with any special access as well.

Comment: There are a large number of reasons that a user can obtain write access to an Account related record, so we need a lot more detail here. What are the relative positions of the team member, the Opp owner, and the Account owner in the role hierarchy? Are there any sharing rules in place? Does the user have Edit All access on Opportunity? Are you using standard page layouts or VIsualforce pages for Opportunity?

Comment: Try clicking the `sharing` button on the record to see more specific reasons.

Answer (score -2):

You can add team members to an opportunity you own.Only the opportunity’s owner or users above the owner in the role hierarchy can add, edit, or delete opportunity team members.

Comment: In which case is it possible that an opp team member  with read only access can also edit the opp? If he is not above owner in hierarchy level.